# Pre-compiled over source code - how can I reverse engineer it?

Tags: asp.net, visual-studio-2008, code-behind, publishing

Is there a way to reverse engineer a pre-compiled website .... if for example someone 8) was silly enough to publish their site to a virtual directory witha  local path set to the project folder in VS2008?

Help :)

Comment: You should be using source control.

Comment: Maybe he's taking over for a developer that sucked and got fired. I had to do this and this was the situation I was in. I used reflector. I use source control. The other guy *says* he did, but that he "lost" the source...

Answer (score 3):

Reflector is difficult to use with a precompiled site because of the way it breaks up the pages. It is not always clear and not an easy way to reverse engineer.

In fact, one of the main reasons we precompile sites is becuase it is harder to reverse engineer and update production code.

Comment: why the downvote? I am interested to find out if others have had different experiences.

Comment: I'm not the one who downvoted you.  I actually voted you up, because my experience using Reflector on a precompiled web site was similar.  However, I still think it's the easiest option if you're stuck. (which is why I voted @BrialLy up as well).  Are you aware of any tools that do it better?

Answer (score 2):

You should be able to use [Reflector](http://www.red-gate.com/products/reflector/) to see the source code. There are plugins which will decompile an assembly (.DLL or .EXE) created with .NET into a new Visual Studio project.

Answer (score 0):

I had the similar issue and used Reflector to Decompile it. I got the source code, then changed the bit I wanted, and rebuild it. Then I copied that dll again to Production site. It started to reflect my changes. It was very easy and not at all difficult, maybe because Precompiled site had dlls for every page, and was updatable , so had only code-behind file in dll.

For reference: http://www.reflector.net/